# Corrupt Firefox Add-on

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to create a Firefox add-on but it doesn't work out at all.
I tried to find the solution but I found nothing useful yet.
Firefox version is 94.0 (64-bit).

The structure of the add-on:

- icons folder

  - l16.png
  - l32.png
  - l48.png
  - l128.png
- background.js
- manifest.json

manifest.json

```
{
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Popup",
   "version": "1.0",
   "content_scripts": [{ 
       "js": ["background.js"],
       "matches": [ "*://example/aaa/*", "*://examp.aaa.bb.cc/*"],
       "all_frames": true }],
    "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "icons": {
        "16": "icons/l16.png",
        "32": "icons/l32.png",
        "48": "icons/l48.png",
        "128": "icons/l128.png"}
}
```

background.js

```
//background.js
const apps = [
  ['AAA', 'https://example/aaa/'],
  ['BBB', 'http://examp.aaa.bb.cc/']
]

browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  browser.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true, 'currentWindow': true }, 
  (tabs) => {
    let url = tabs[0].url;
    const i = apps.findIndex(u => url.includes(u[1]));
    if (i > -1 && !sessionStorage.getItem(url)) {
        sessionStorage.setItem(url, url);
        browser.tabs.update( tabs[0].id, { url: `http://popup.aaa.bb.cc?title=${apps[i][0]}`} ); 
    }   
  });
})
```

I create a zip from this folder and the two files and then I upload it as temporary extension, because when I try to upload it as a normal add-on Firefox says it is corrupted.
So the uploaded add-n in temporary extension container gives back "Error: Can't find profile directory.".
Chrome much more simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your background scripts [need to be separated from your content scripts in the manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension).

```
"background": {
  "scripts": [
    "background.js"
  ]
},
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://example/aaa/*", "*://examp.aaa.bb.cc/*"],
  "js": [
    "content.js"
  ]
}],
```

Comment: Hi, I see but I wanted to use only content_scripts due to simplification the extension so I deleted background from manifest.json and I used  its script (background.js) in content_scripts. Or I cannot use browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener in content_scripts?

Comment: Extension documentation can be complicated to work around but Google seems to be very specific that [you can't use tabs.query, for example, with content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#get-the-current-tab).